# How to make short account number

Tags: mysql, database

I have project and every user has own account number. The problem is account numbers is 7 digits (from 1000000 to 9999999) and i want them to 5 digits (easy to remember and payment companies). 
I know internet provider they have around 3 million users but they give 5 digit account number, how? Is there any way?

Comment: So you want to update the account# from 1000000 to 10000?

Comment: Just numbers. Or letters and numbers? Can other information about the user also be incorporated (e.g. Username)

Comment: only numbers. May be they have some incorporation with username but they give only 5 digit numbers. You can pay with it.

Comment: It's impossible to uniquely enumerate 3,000,000 users in base 10 with only 5 digits.

Comment: @Drakes Is it possible to make 7 digits to 6 digit?

Comment: If you can guarantee the number of unique users you have does not exceed 10^5-1, then you can map their given account number to a number in 5-digit space, possibly using the auto-incrementing primary key you mentioned.

Comment: my credit card number is 16 digits long and i remember it fine. If remembering the account number is important, and its only 7 digits long, they will remember it

Comment: @pala_ now people getting so lazy, you remember others not, even never tries. I am just trying to make as much as easy

Comment: @Newmaster Any luck with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you thought about using a number system of a higher base like 16 (Hex http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) or even higher. This should shorten your number. Hope I understood you question right.

Comment: actually i have MySQL accouts table auto creates PRIMARY KEY. hex to decimal is not as i want because 1000000(decimal) = F4240 (hex) and this can't be account number

Comment: Well, you cleary cant store 3 million different values in 5 digits. So unless you use letters this wont work.